# self.get_secure_cookie returns None, but cookie exists

Tags: python, cookies, tornado

I have a strange error, when check cookie in Tornado`s **WebSocketHandler**:

```
class MyHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print(self.get_secure_cookie("cookie"))
```

It returns **None**, but in browser I can see that cookie (in another login-handler I use `self.set_secure_cookie("cookie", "123")`)

How to fix that?

Thanks!

**Update**

if I use `self.request.headers` I only have:

```
{
'Pragma': 'no-cache', 
'Sec-Websocket-Version': '13', 
'Connection': 'Upgrade', 
'Upgrade': 'websocket', 
'Host': 'localhost:8888', 
'Sec-Websocket-Key': 'key', 
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 
'User-Agent': 'u-a', 
'Sec-Websocket-Extensions': 'x-webkit-deflate-frame', 
'Origin': 
'http://127.0.0.1:8888'
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about what's going on here?

Comment: @JakobWeisblat I want to check, if user logging in, when he used web sockets

Comment: What path is that cookie set for?

Comment: @21Zoo default path - /, I set cookie on page "login". web socket chat on - /

Comment: Did you check via the dev tools of your browser if a) the cookie is set and b) if it's send during the websocket request?

Comment: @21Zoo of course I check, the cookie is set on login page and I see cookie in dev tools. And don't know how to check, when it sends during web socket request

Comment: Looked into this a bit more and seems like I was wrong. Check out https://github.com/nellessen/Tornado-Redis-Chat 
In that example they send the username cookie per websocket and then validate that so that's probably the way to go, sorry bout the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have started use **wss://** and it works

Comment: I had to access the page from `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` for the cookie to work.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer here: [User authentication in tornado websocket application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412665/user-authentication-in-tornado-websocket-application)

`self.request.headers` should contain what you're looking for.