# Socket.io (or node.js) and Cookies

Tags: node.js, cookies, socket.io

I have an application that saves a cooke and would like to get hold of that cookie from node.js and Socket.io, while the application is running on the same server as my node app, they are on different ports.

Can I do this and how? (needs to work in IE 8+, FF, Chrome and Safari)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an idiot and forgot that socket.io works both ways, so I can just send the cookie to the server on connecting to it! - Here's the link that helped me out: [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311180/how-to-send-cookies-when-connecting-to-socket-io-via-websockets)