# ZfcUser and the SessionHandler in Ratchet

Tags: session, symfony, zend-framework2, zfcuser, ratchet

I'm want to be able to view the [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) sessions in the [I/O server](http://socketo.me/docs/server) of [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/).

However, out of the box only [Symphony 2 Sessions](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) are supported with the [SessionProvider](http://socketo.me/docs/sessions) of [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/).

And I seriously don't know what to do next to make this work.

--

1. Either extend the ZfcUser to use the Symphony 2 Session.
2. Make the SessionProvider of Ratchet work with the way ZfcUser handles his Sessions.
3. Or a workaround were I save the sessions to a database and use a `SELECT` query on the I/O server? ( like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311180/how-to-send-cookies-when-connecting-to-socket-io-via-websockets) )

--

The way Ratchet uses the SessionProvider is like this:

```
use Ratchet\Session\SessionProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler;
use Ratchet\App;

$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);

$session = new SessionProvider(
    new MyApp
  , new Handler\MemcacheSessionHandler($memcache)
);

$server = new App('localhost');
$server->route('/sessDemo', $session);
$server->run();
```

Any ideas on how to go furter?